# How to find table>tr with data-value

Tags: jquery

I made a table, and put some data like this with jQuery.

```
for(var i = 0; i < trlist.length; i++){
    if(i == makeLine) {
        var addTR = $(".table_tr:eq(1)").clone();
        addTR.css("background-color", "gray");
        addTR.show();
        $(".mytable").append("newTr");
    }

    var newTr = $(".table_tr:eq(0)").clone();
    newTr.data("trnum", i);
    for(var j = 0; j < tdlist.length; j++){  }
    newTr.show();
    $(".mytable").append(newTr);
}
```

I want to get all `td`'s data-seq which in the same row when I click one `td`. 
so I try to find tr with `data-trnum` but it does not work. I think I did really wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

```
var tableTr = $("tr[data-trnum=" + trnum + "]");
var td = tableTr.children();
var arrDateList = new Array();

td.each(function(i){
    arrDateList.push(td.eq(i).data("seq"));
});
```

Comment: _when I click one td._ So where is the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood your needs, you must attach a click event to the `td`'s then get the siblings `data-seq` attribute like :

```js
$('.mytable').on('click', 'td', function() {
  var arrDateList = $(this).siblings().map(function(){
    return $(this).data('seq');
  }).get();

  console.log(arrDateList);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable" border=1>
  <tr class="table_tr">
    <td data-seq="A1">A1</td>
    <td data-seq="A2">A2</td>
    <td data-seq="A3">A3</td>
    <td data-seq="A4">A4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table_tr">
    <td data-seq="B1">B1</td>
    <td data-seq="B2">B2</td>
    <td data-seq="B3">B3</td>
    <td data-seq="B4">B4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you